# Dynamic text postition in Density plot

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a density plot with the percentiles split. The following is my code,

```
      d <- density(x)
        plot(d)
        tot <- sum(d$y)
     qs <- sapply(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75,1), function (i) max(which(cumsum(d$y) <= tot*i)))

lines(x = d$x[qs], y = d$y[qs], type = "h")

text(x = d$x[qs]-3,y=0.015, labels = c("25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"))
```

Can we change the text to a dynamic one which gets the values from the previous statement and places the text in appropriate place?

Also is there a way we can give colors to different percentiles? So that less than 25 will have one color and it goes on...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `d$x[qs]` contains only three values, so for the last text object the 1st x position will be repeated. For colouring have a look at `?polygon`.

Comment: I am fine with that. My concern is with respect to position of the text. I am planning to loop it with many data and for each data the percentiles would be different. So can't pick a fixed position. That's why looking to find if there are any dynamic way to positioning it

Comment: I'm not sure if I undestand your question in detail, but `x = d$x[qs]` is dynamic and refers to the respective percentiles as in your `line` command.